# Display CPT taxonomies as an archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

Hello Stack Exchange people,

I created a custom post type called `articles`. 
I also created a taxonomy `city` for that specific post type.

I can create a custom post and set a city to it and it gives me the url I'm wishing to read this page.

```
https://www.example.com/blog/city_name/title_of_the_article/
```

The thing I wish to do is to create a city page that will act like the regular `archive.php` but just for the city of the custom post types.

For example, I created an article with a city set to "*Tunis*" so my URL is:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/tunis/my_article/
```

I would like this url: `https://www.example.com/blog/tunis/`
to be the archive page for the article with the city set to "*Tunis*".

I ran multiple tests but it didn't work (404 error).

For info, I don't have a `archive-city.php` page created.

Here is my code for CPT and the taxonomy.
(For now and considering the code I'm showing, the archive page is available at:
`https://www.example.com/blog/articles/`)

```
register_post_type( 'article', 
    array( 'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Articles', 
        'singular_name' => 'Article', 
        'all_items' => 'All article', 
        'add_new' => 'Add article', 
        'add_new_item' => 'Add article',
        'edit' => 'Edit article', 
        'edit_item' =>  'Edit article', 
        'new_item' => 'New article', 
        'view_item' => 'View article', 
        'search_items' => 'Search article', 
        'not_found' =>  'Nothing found in the Database.', 
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nothing found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    ), 

    'description' => 'This is the example custom post type', 
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_position' => 10, 
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog', 
    'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'adresses', 'with_front' => true ), 
    'has_archive' => 'articles', 
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),

    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail' )));
```

and

```
function resource_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'city', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'snt' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'city', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'snt' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Add city', 'snt' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All city', 'snt' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent city', 'snt' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent city:', 'snt' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New city', 'snt' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New city', 'snt' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit city', 'snt' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update city', 'snt' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View city', 'snt' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'snt' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove city', 'snt' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'snt' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular city', 'snt' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search city', 'snt' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'snt' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No article', 'snt' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'snt' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'snt' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'rewrite'                    => array('slug' => 'city')
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'city', array( 'article' ), $args );
} 
add_action( 'init', 'resource_type', 0 );
```

To get `https://www.example.com/blog/city/` as the archive page, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you gone to Settings > Permalinks and clicked **Save Changes**? You must do that once after defining a new tax or CPT.

Comment: what @Peter says AND you have to register your taxonomy BEFORE the post type, otherwise you can't make them work together in an URL

Comment: and in your `register_post_type` you define `'taxonomies' => array('category')`, but where is your taxonomy `city`..? shouldn't it say `'taxonomies' => array('category', 'city')` or `'taxonomies' => array('city')`?

Answer (score 1):

You're describing the default behaviour. Based on your code, you will have the following URLs:

- https://www.url.com/blog/addresses/ The archive of all Articles.
- https://www.url.com/blog/city/tunis/ The archive of all Articles assigned to the Tunis City.
- https://www.url.com/blog/addresses/article-title/ The single Article.

If any of these URLs are returning a 404, you likely just need to flush your permalinks. This needs to be done once after registering a post type for the first time. Visiting the *Settings > Permalinks* page is sufficient to do this (you don't even need to press save, unless you make a change on the page).

As for the templates to use:

- https://www.url.com/blog/addresses/ Will use `archive-article.php`, if it exists, `archive.php` if it doesn't, and `index.php` if that doesn't exist either.
- https://www.url.com/blog/city/tunis/ Will use `taxonomy-city.php`, if it exists, `taxonomy.php` if it doesn't, `archive.php` if that doesn't exist, and `index.php` if none of those exist.

You can see an explanation and visualisation of the template hierarchy [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

An important thing to remember is that the templates for these all need to use the same [main loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) as all other templates:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        // Display post content
    endwhile; 
endif; 
?>
```

WordPress will automatically query the correct posts to be displayed by this loop, so you should *not* be using a custom `WP_Query` to query posts in these templates.

Comment: thank for your help, will try asap

Comment: I tried to do the permalink validation as suggested. https://www.url.com/blog/addresses/ is bringing to 404 error, https://www.url.com/blog/city/tunis/ is working, and https://www.url.com/blog/addresses/article-title/ is not working either. 

As for the templates, thank you for all the info